# how to open call log from broadcastreceiver

Tags: broadcastreceiver, calllog

how to open call log from broadcastreceiver

```
am using a broadcast receiver to monitor call is coming from which number...

and for that i need to open calllog to show to the user

how to open call log from broadcastreceiver?
```

Answer (score 0):

After a long search in stackoverflow.com

now i can open call log from broadcast receiver using

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("content://call_log/calls"));
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(i);
```